# jQuery - Fill out variables in textarea using next button

Tags: jquery

I have a textarea that is filled with text with @variable where the user needs to replace it with whatever they type into an input field and then move on to the next @variable.

HTML:

```
<textarea name="description" id="description">
Today is @variable. Tomorrow is @variable. More text here and here and here. 
What is 3 x 4? @variable
</textarea>
<input name="variable_fill" id="variable" type="text">
<div id="button_change"><button id="find_next">Start</button></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
$("#find_next").on("click", function(e) {
$(variable).focus();
    $(button_change).html('<button id="find_next">Next</button>');

    // Find the first @variable in the textarea, user fills in the variable using the text field,then clicks nexts, it replaces the @variable with what they typed, then moves on to the next @variable, and so on. When all @variable are filled out the "Next" button dissapears 
    });
    var variable_count = 3 // After a @variable is filled out and replaced count reduces
    if(variable_count == 0){
    $(button_change).text('Finished Filling Out Variables!');
    }
});
```

After I click the button how do I tell javascript to look at the contents of the textarea, find the variable, replace it and then move onto the next one?

And is it possible for the "@variable" to be highlighted with a background color so that the user knows which "@varible" they are filling out?

I have created a fiddle to get it started
https://jsfiddle.net/t3kkgvbg/7/

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: @zaki sorry, I have updated the question. In my comments in the JS I have explained what I'm trying to do

Comment: Does this have to be achieved using a text area?

Answer (score 1):

```
val = $('#description').val();
var variable_count = (val.match(/@variable/g) || []).length;

if(variable_count == 0){
    $(button_change).text('Finished Filling Out Variables!');
    }else{
   val = val.replace(/@variable/,"Replacement");
$('#description').val(val);
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/t3kkgvbg/8/

Answer (score 1):

How does something like this sound? Without additional flags, the replace function only replaces the first entry, so this works quite well with our problem. We would need to call this once for each replacement.

```
function setVariable(myNewString) {
  var myTextArea = $("#description");
  var myText = myTextArea.val();
  myText = myText.replace("@variable", myNewString);
  myTextArea.val(myText);
}
```

Where myNewString is the value you want to replace the entry "@variable" with. This can be made into a oneliner if we want, but has been written on several lines for clarity.

This does not highlight the text, which would be a different problem.

Comment: Thanks for giving an explanation on your answer, other than just a very low quality code dump answer.

Answer (score 0):

Script-

```
 <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#find_next").on("click", function () {              
                //replace text 
$("#description").text($("#description").text().replace("@variable",$("#variable").val()));
                    $("#variable").val('');//make text box blank
                    if ($("#description").text().split("@variable").length == 1) {
                        $("#button_change").html("Finished Filling Out Variables!");
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Your Html should be

```
    <textarea name="description" id="description">
    Today is @variable. Tomorrow is @variable. More text here and here and here. 
    What is 3 x 4? @variable
    </textarea>
    <input name="variable_fill" id="variable" type="text">
    <div id="button_change">
        <button id="find_next">Start</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like that :

Its works

```
$(function() {
  $("#find_next").click(function() {
     // if presence of @variable
     if($('#description').html().indexOf('@variable') > -1){
       $('#description').html($('#description').html().replace("@variable",$('#variable').val()));
       $('#variable').val("");    
     }

     if(!($('#description').html().indexOf('@variable') > -1)){
         $(button_change).text('Finished Filling Out Variables!');
     }
  });
});
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/t3kkgvbg/9/

Answer (score 0):

Here you are :-)

```js
$(function() {  
  var variable_count = $("#description").html().split("@variable").length - 1;
  var count = 0;   
  $("#find_next").on("click", function(e) {
    var value = $("#variable").val();
    if (value == "") return;   
    $(this).html("Next");  
    $("#description").find(".mark").first().replaceWith(value);    
    $("#variable").val('').focus();
    count += 1;   
    if (count == variable_count) {
      $("#variable").hide();
      $("#button_change").html('Finished Filling Out Variables!');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#description {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

#variable {
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

button {
  padding: 10px;
}

.mark {
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <div name="description" id="description">
    Today is <span class="mark">@variable</span>. Tomorrow is <span class="mark">@variable</span>. More text here and here and here. What is 3 x 4? <span class="mark">@variable</span>.
  </div>
</p>
<input name="variable_fill" id="variable" type="text">
<div id="button_change">
  <button id="find_next">Start</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks great! I should have been more clear in my questions. Can the green background be on the "@variable" that the user is filling out to keep it easy to follow? Also the variable_count shouldn't be hard coded as the the textarea might have any number of "@variable"s